# Problem importing external module with typescript (newb)

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, export

I'm a newbie at JS and especially Typescript. I'm using npm 6.2.0 with typescript 3.0.1. I'm trying to import the "file-saver" module and use it. Its `index.d.ts` looks like this:

```
declare namespace FileSaver {
    function saveAs(data: Blob, filename?: string, disableAutoBOM?: boolean): void;
}
declare global {
    const saveAs: typeof FileSaver.saveAs;

    interface Window {
        saveAs: typeof FileSaver.saveAs;
    }
}
export = FileSaver;
```

When I import that in my code (tried various ways, here's the latest):

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
// later...
saveAs(blob, 'stuff.json');
```

rollup gives me this error:

```
build/js/src/ngl.js → build/js/ngl.dev.js, build/js/ngl.esm.js...
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding 
  to external modules
file-saver (guessing 'fileSaver')
```

and my code doesn't work in the browser (Chrome). I get this at runtime:

```
viewer.js:915 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveAs' of undefined
    at Viewer.__render (viewer.js:915)
    at Viewer.render (viewer.js:947)
    at viewer.js:745
```

Here's my `rollup.config.js` (slightly shortened for SO):

```
import buble from 'rollup-plugin-buble';
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

var path = require('path');
var pkg = require('./package.json');
var external = Object.keys(pkg.dependencies);

...

export default {
  input: 'build/js/src/app.js',
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true
    }),
    commonjs({
      namedExports: {
        'node_modules/chroma-js/chroma.js': [ 'scale' ],
        'node_modules/signals/dist/signals.js': [ 'Signal' ],
        'node_modules/sprintf-js/src/sprintf.js': [ 'sprintf' ]
      }
    }),
    json(),
    buble()
  ],
  output: [
    {
      file: "build/js/app.dev.js",
      format: 'umd',
      name: 'App',
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: "build/js/app.esm.js",
      format: 'es',
      name: 'App',
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  external: external
};
```

Comment: Please add your `rollup.config.js` to the question.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen, added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `external` option from `rollup.config.js`.  This option is telling Rollup that the `file-saver` module should be omitted from the bundle because it will be available in your target environment; in the browser, this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.